# BackgroundAudioAgent with a dynamic playlist

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-audio

I am developing an app that has the capability of playing audio tracks streamed from a server. This app needs to be able to playback the audio even when the screen is locked or if the app is put in background.

=====

For background audio playback in windows phone, the Background Audio Agent is required.

The sample provided by Microsoft shows the basics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx

In the sample, the background audio agent has a list of static tracks and when the user taps the skip/prev in the main project, it simply forwards it to the singleton BackgroundAudioPlayer object which in turn uses the event handler in BackgroundAudioAgent project to load the next/prev song.

BUT, what I would think a common usecase is that the main project will have the details of the play list (like a list retrieved from server) and we just need the backgroundaudio agent to forward that request to the main project.

My question is

1. Is there ANY way to forward the user action from audio agent to the main project so the main project can determine which track to play?

P.S: I cannot use MediaElement (which seemed to work fine in Window Store App and provides background support) because in Windows Phone SDK it has no background support.

**EDIT:** When the screen is locked, The application itself can be terminated even if the background agent is running, so I guess there no mechanism to forward the request to the app. This would mean, The background agent has to be self sufficient... Which would be a poor design to have to jump through hoops for a seemingly common behavior (Playing audio stored in remote server that requires authentication) .

At this point, I am considering writing all URL specific information to a file and have the background audio agent read that saved file and authenticate with server and create audio tracks. But the handshake to show the current audio information when the application resumes will be complex to say the least.

I hope I am wrong with this and there is actually a easier way than this. Would love to see how others have handled this.

Comment: Background is background. if you need to make a request, make it. Otherwise prepare a playlist in a main app, and save it into IsoStorage/Database. For extended scenarios use Background Audio Streaming  (sample here code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Background-Audio-Streamer-e85b8deb)

Comment: Well. Replicating code from the main application into the audioagent is quite (unnecessary) complication. I prefer the iOS or Android implementation to be much better. In any case, I have dumped it to filesystem and have the agent read from it and it works.. But it is Cumbersome, crude and frankly not a good system.

Comment: You can reuse the code making a dedicated assembly and reference it in background/app.